# Adding TranslateZoomRotateBehavior doesn't fire MouseLeftButtonUp

Tags: wpf, expression, expression-blend-4

I have an application which uses Expression Blend's [TranslateZoomRotateBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723978(v=expression.40).aspx) which allows me to zoom or rotate my rectangle element.

After applying the said element, the existing MouseLeftButtonUp event won't trigger anymore when I am pinching the screen.

When I tried removing the element, MouseLeftButtonUp is working.

Is there a way that TranslateZoomRotateBehavior can coexist with MouseLeftButtonUp?

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: You could try to handle the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp event. But please post some code that can be used to reproduce your issue when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is by any chance the control hosting your rectangle with unset or transparent background?